# Lots of variables, best approach without nested loops

Tags: c++, nested-loops, cartesian-product

I’m in need of some help and guidance on the design of my code. I want to run tests with multiple variables set to multiple values, without creating insane amounts of nested loops. I got a struct which holds various variables like this (only three integers as an example, but the real deal will hold a lot more, including booleans, doubles etc):

```cpp
struct VarHolder
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    // etc..
    // etc..
};
```

The struct get passed into a test function.

```cpp
bool TestFunction(const VarHolder& _varholder)
{
    // ...
}
```

I want to run the test for all variables ranging for a their set range, all combinations of the variables. One way is to create a loop for each variable:

```cpp
for (int a = 0; a < 100; a++)
{
  for (int b = 10; b < 90; b++)
    {
      for (int c = 5; c < 65; c++)
        {
          //...
          //...

             //set variables
             VarHolder my_varholder(a, b, c /*, ...*/);
             TestFunction(my_varholder);
        }
    }
}
```

But this seems inefficient and gets unreadable fast as the amount of variables gets bigger. What is an elegant way to achieve this? One crux is that the variables will change in the future, removing some, adding new one’s etc. so some solution without rewriting loops for each variable as they change is preferable.

Comment: Why tagging as java/c#/c++?   For c# -> You should check [reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection)

Comment: An elegant way is to refactor your masive struct into smaller pieces of logical units instead of having a single massive class/struct with some hard to understand dependencies between their members.

Comment: You might create ranges, then use (or create (if not available in your language/libraries)) cartesian product (view) or these ranges.

Comment: already the name `Varholder` suggests that you didnt really think your design through. If this is a collection of a huge number of members and you cannot give a better name to it, then that is your actual problem

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen  I’d tagged multiple languages because the question isn’t only applicable for one specific language. On the other hand I didn’t realize there are language-specific functions available so I changed the tags to c++ only. Thanks.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Naming of functions, classes or structs is beside the point here, these are just some example scrambling’s to explain the problem.

Comment: @Jarod42 A cartesian product looks promising.

Comment: You should tag only the language you're actually using so that the appropriate answer(s) may be given without distraction. C++, C# and Java are _completely_, _entirely_, _wholly_ separate and independent languages with essentially no relationship between them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3), you might use `cartesian_product` view:

```
auto as = ranges::view::ints(0, 100);
auto bs = ranges::view::ints(10, 90);
auto cs = ranges::view::ints(5, 65);
// ...
// might be other thing that `int`

for (const auto& t : ranges::view::cartesian_product(as, bs, cs /*, ...*/))
{
    std::apply(
        [](const auto&... args) {
            VarHolder my_varHolder{args...};
            Test(my_varHolder);
        },
        t);
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. De library contains some other interesting features as well.